# Matrix Vector Multiply Notation

Tags: matrices, vectors

I just want to ask a question about a notation used in one paper. There is something like:

$\ldots = \mathbf C * \mathbf x$

where the $\mathbf C$ is a matrix $\mathbf C \in \mathbb R^{1000*1000}$ and $\mathbf x$ is a vector $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^{3*1}$.

How am I supposed to understand such a multiplying?

Thanks...

**EDIT:**

The paper can be found here: [novelty FastICA](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/NPL99.pdf)

and I'm talking about the equation (6).

Comment: Can you provide the paper in question? Right now, the question cannot be answered (too few details)

Comment: http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/NPL99.pdf

Comment: Why do you think that $x$ in your example is an element of $\mathbb R^{3\times 1}$?

Comment: I wanted to make the question simple but it seems it's not going to work :) OK, so the vector $\mathbf x$ I write about above is actually outcome of the  $E\{\mathbf x g(\mathbf w^T \mathbf x)\}$ where $\mathbf x$ is a sample, let's say $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^{3*1}$ and $\mathbf w$ is a weight $\mathbf w \in \mathbb R^{3*1}$ and so outcome of this part of the formula, the part I am interested, is $something \in \mathbb R^{3*1}$...

Comment: And, when it comes to $\mathbf C$, $\mathbf C$ is a covariance matrix of all the samples we have and if we have 1000 samples than the covariance matrix dimension is 1000*1000...

Comment: sure, $x\in \mathbb R^{3\times 1}$, but $Ex$ does not have the same dimensions of $x$, it has as many rows as $E$...

Comment: And I forgot to mention that $\mathbf E\{ \}$ denotes averaging the outcome of the multiplying by the number of samples...

Comment: but $C=E(xx^T),$ so clearly $C$ cannot have a different dimension than $x$...

Comment: Hmm, I'm missing the point, can you be a little bit more specific, perhaps with some example maybe...

Comment: if $x\in\mathbb R^n$, then $xx^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, meaning that $C=E(xx^T)$ is also in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, so you can easily calculate $C\cdot x$ in the standard "matrix times vector" way.

Comment: I see, thanks...